# Trying to have multiple turtles running and drawing at the same time NOT on a straight line

Tags: python, while-loop, turtle-graphics

I'm currently trying to have multiple turtles running at the same time to draw a sun and its rays, i'd like to draw both of them at the same time. I need other things to run also at the same time of them but once i get how to do with two, it shouldn't be that difficult to do it with more. I tried to look for answer here but i only found turtles running together on a straight line, no idea how to do it on different shapes, don't know if it's even possible.

EDIT: Thanks for the warning of not to upload images of code, i'll upload the code with the right method, sorry it was my first time here.

Sun and Rays def code:

```
 def drawCircle(x,y,r):
    sun.pu()
    sun.goto(turtle_size/2 - screen.window_width()/2.7, turtle_size/2 + screen.window_height()/4.2)
    sun.fillcolor("yellow")
    sun.pendown()
    sun.begin_fill()
    sun.pos()
    global Xs
    Xs=sun.pos()
    print(Xs)
    sun.circle(r)
    sun.end_fill()
def drawFourRays(t, length, radius):
    for i in range(4):
        t.penup()
        t.forward(radius)
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(length)
        t.penup()
        t.backward(length + radius)
        t.left(90)
```

While true:

```
while True:
    drawCircle(-279.44,149.00,60)
    sun.penup()
    sun.goto(turtle_size/2 - screen.window_width()/2.7, turtle_size/2 + screen.window_height()/4.2)
    sun.lt(90)
    sun.fd(60)
    sun.pendown()
    drawFourRays(sun, 65, 62)
    sun.right(45)
    drawFourRays(sun, 65, 62)
    sun.left(45)
```

Tried to define the sun and the rays and put them in a while True expecting them to run together but they are drawn one before the other.
I'm sorry if there are any rookie mistake, i just started programming

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: If you want a finished solution, I did this some time ago: https://gitlab.com/zvone/threaded_turtle You can also use it to draw ideas for your implementation.

Comment: zvone i read what you sent to me but i don't understand how can i implement your implementations in my phyton, do i need to install them somewhere? Just paste them all inside every code where i want to run multiple turtles at once?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a minimal example of a simpler solution than threads or timer events -- just rearranging your loops:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drawCircle(t, radius):
    t.sety(t.ycor() - radius)

    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(radius)
    t.end_fill()

    t.sety(t.ycor() + radius)

def drawEightRays(t, length, radius):
    for distance in range(length):
        for _ in range(8):
            t.forward(radius)
            t.pendown()
            t.forward(distance)
            t.penup()
            t.backward(distance + radius)
            t.left(45)

        screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

sun = Turtle()
sun.hideturtle()
sun.fillcolor('yellow')
sun.penup()

drawCircle(sun, 60)
drawEightRays(sun, 65, 65)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thanks cdlane but like that it only draw the eight rays together;
however i think i understood that using "screen.update()" in a double "for" like that keeps update the screen every time the inside "for" end(?); 
so basically the second "for" draws 8 point, check if the condition are still satisfied and restart if yes?

However this doesn't answer completely my question, that is how to draw both (and possibly my whole draw), at the same time...
do I need to put everything in a big "for" cycle with every single turtle in a sub-"for" cycle and use "screen.update()" as you did there?